# Get smaller images to load in full quality when hovered over and enlarged

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, reactjs

I have a list of items which contain an image and some text.

```js
<ul id = "results"> {
  JSON.parse(this.state.data).resultCards.map(function(card) {
    return <li> <img src = {
      'https://image.deckbrew.com/mtg/multiverseid/'+.multiverseid +'.jpg'
    }
    />{card.deviation}</li > ;
  })
} < /ul>
```

For purposes of screen real estate, the images are loaded at a smaller size, and then re-enlarged to full size (311px) when hovered over. (This is a .scss stylesheet, if that matters.)

```css
/* The card images within the list items. */
ul li img{
    height: 175px;
    padding: 3px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

/* Those images when hovered over. */
ul li img:hover{
    height: 311px
}
```

The problem is that when the images are enlarged, they look fuzzy and low quality, since I assume they've been loaded at the smaller resolution. Is there any way to force the images to be loaded at full resolution, so that when hovering occurs, the resulting full-scale image looks normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay what I think the best thing to do is to load the images and then scale them down and back up again. This will maintain the aspect ratio, and should handle resolution all in css. an example of this would be

```
transform: scale(0.6, 0.6);
-ms-transform: scale(0.6, 0.6);
-webkit-transform: scale(0.6, 0.6);
```

This would scale the images down to 60%, then you can scale them back up the same way. You could also use Javascript and load the larger image in ajax, but I think that is a bit overkill. Either way this hopefully should fix you problem. Here is a link for further reading you can do on [CSS3 2D Transform](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp).

Comment: That does indeed work. However in the minimized form the image gets noticeably fuzzier than it has to be (as in, you see it shrink from the full size down to the 60% size, and half a second later it gets slightly fuzzier). Is there any rendering property (antialias or something) I can set for this?

Comment: Also, this means that the list container is as big as if the image were at 100% size permanently (even with the image shrunk down), which slightly negates the point of shrinking it (to save space). Is there any way to shrink the list container item with the image?

Comment: You might want to use the transition-duration: property to control the state the transition. This might be one way to control the ease In and out of the image changing, and hopefully with this you can eliminate the fuzziness. As for the container, after the transformation you would need to resize that. Here is a link to the [CSS Transition](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/transitions/). Also you might want to look at using [JQuery](https://jquery.com), they have a great library to handle animation.

Comment: To handle the container you might be able to set it to the smaller size and then use the overflow: property to allow the image to be rendered outside of its container. You would do this by setting the overflow:visible. Another way is also to set a default size for this container as well, this would be done by passing the property the initial keyword. Here is a link to [CSS3 Overflow and Keywords](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp).

Comment: How do I set a default size on something, and what would I be setting it on? Does 'container' in this case mean the ul li component, since the image is ul li img? Also, from your link, overflow defaults to 'visible', so I don't need to change anything there.